# Android: Bound Service or Singleton

Tags: android

Im creating an offline chatbot and was wondering if it would be good practice to use a Bound Service or a Singleton for the parsing/response Engine?

Answer (score 2):

Service and Singleton are two different concepts.

We use `Singleton` is a pattern to initiate and use one instance only.

Service is a component for  longer-running operation that runs in background.

`Bound Service`:

A [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) is the server in a client-server interface. Service that binds several applications or Activities.

> Im creating an offline chatbot ..

If you think to develop Program  talks to other application, bear in mind that on Android, one process cannot normally access the memory of another process. I offer you to  use [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) (Android Interface Definition Language)